# Union-find algorithm not working for finding number of connected components(HackerEarth)

Tags: python-3.x, graph-theory, union-find

I tried implementing Union-find algorithm for finding number of connected components in a graph.
Problem link - https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/connected-components-in-a-graph/
Problem code in python -

```
def cc(n,edges):
    length=len(edges)
    l=[-1]*(n+1)
    rank=[0]*(n+1)
    for i in range(length):
        a=edges[i][0]
        b=edges[i][1]
        union(a,b,rank,l)
    count=0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if l[i]==-1:
            count+=1
    print(count)
def union(a,b,rank,l):
    fromp=find(a,l)
    top=find(b,l)
    if rank[fromp]>rank[top]:
        l[top]=fromp
    elif rank[top]>rank[fromp]:
        l[fromp]=top
    else:
        l[fromp]=top
        rank[top]+=1
def find(a,l):
    if l[a]==-1:
        return a
    par=find(l[a],l)
    l[a]=par
    return par
n,e=map(int,input().split())
edges=[]
for _ in range(e):
    edges.append(list(map(int,input().split())))
cc(n,edges)
```

The code is not working and giving wrong answers and even runtime error for one test case.Could anyone please help?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. What does "not working" mean? What wrong answers does it give? What are the error messages for the runtime errors?

Comment: Thank you. The runtime error is "Maximum recursion depth exceeded". The testcases are not visible but it is giving wrong answers for two testcases.

Comment: Did you try building your own testcases and trying to find some that get wrong results?

Comment: Yes, It works for them and I couldn't figure it out.